# xsl template matching with text()

Tags: xslt, text, match

I'm trying to use a an xsl:template with the following:

```
xsl:template match="/a/b/c/d/text() = 'Foo'"
```

But I get an error from XMLSpy...:
Invalid Pattern: Unexcpected token - "= 'Foo'"

Anyone has any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the `d` elements then use `match="/a/b/c/d[. = 'Foo']"`, if you need to match the text node children of the `d` elements then use `match="/a/b/c/d/text()[. = 'Foo']"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match='/a/b/c/d[text() = "Foo"]'>
```

`text() = "Foo"` is a comparison, and in XPath this means it must be inside a predicate - in square brackets.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a short explanation to your code answer?